# force git ignore ssl regardless of configs?

Tags: git, github

I've read lots of related topics.
Already tried both
`git config --global http.sslVerify false`
and
`export GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=true`
It solves the problem *"Received HTTP code 407 from proxy after CONNECT"* for a single repo.
But in case of recursive cloning, it clones main repo successfully and gives same error for each of submodules.
Same errors with using from Vundle after *:PluginInstall* (no wonder - it executes same recursive clones). Want force git to ignore ssl more strictly than global .gitconfig . Is that possible?

P.S.: ssl-handshake problems happen only working with github. At company got to work over proxy..

Comment: HTTP 407 means "407 Proxy Authentication Required" hence you have to provide username and password to the proxy you use. This has nothing to do with SSL/TLS.

Comment: I've provided it all at /etc/environment

Comment: and apt update/upgrade from main canonical repos work. internet works in browser after entering same login data as in /etc/environment.
some sites like Yandex force Captcha passing yet. maybe github has same defense mechanisms..

Comment: @Amphyby,  can you clone the submodules individually as a separate repository ? Does it fail with the same error ? Since you claim that the main repo clones with no issues, then probably testing the cloning of a submodule could narrow down the problem ?

Comment: @Amphyby, you could also update the question by adding the output of  ```export GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1; git clone <command>```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
git -c http.sslVerify=false clone <command>
```

The `-c` option makes sure that this `http.sslVerify=false` configuration is followed each time a submodule is cloned.

Comment: yeah, I've seen such comments to other posts. I've tried already. in my case it's again
*Received HTTP code 407 from proxy after CONNECT*

Comment: Code only answers are rarely helpful. Please comment your code or expound on why this is the solution to the question.